# Dynamically setting undefined variables in Twig

Tags: php, twig

I am researching which template engine to use for mail merging in a project and feel that Twig is probably the best choice.

Obviously with a mail-merge there are thousands of variables and it would be very inefficient to load them all with extensive SQL calls when only a handful will be used in a document.  All our variables are in the array form of:

```
{{table.field}}
```

What I need to do is when Twig comes across a "table" variable that is not set, it calls a procedure that will populate it with values. This obviously prevents numerous wasteful calls to the SQL database in an attempt to populate every conceivable variable.

How would I go about this in Twig?

Comment: Does `{{ table.field|default('Hello') }}` satisfy your requirement?

Comment: No, that just sets a default value for a field.

Comment: Then your question isn't clear enough. You want to set a value for something which isn't present, that's the very definition of a default value...